# Conjugacy classes of rational tori in Symplectic group

Tags: finite-groups, algebraic-groups, weyl-group

Rational conjugacy classes of Frobenius stable tori (in a finite group of Lie type) are in bijection with Frobenius-conjugacy classes of the corresponding Weyl group.When the group is the Symplectic group Sp$(2n)$ then the Frobenius action on the Weyl group is trivial and classes of rational tori are in bijection with conjugacy classes of the type C Weyl group $W_n$. These conjugacy classes are parametrized by bipartitions of n.

The groups of Frobenius-stable points, of tori belonging conjugacy class of rational tori, are all isomorphic. Is there a way of constructing these groups from the corresponding bipartition of n? I tried this for Sp(4) but I cannot make much sense of what I got. I also did this computation for GL(n), for this group it is possible (and quite simple).

I hope someone can give me a hint. Thank you in advance. Hans.

Comment: [math.se]: [Conjugacy classes of rational tori in Symplectic group](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3306312) It is recommended to link the other copies when [meta-tag:cross-posting], see: [Cross posts to Math SE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2637#2638).

Comment: On an unrelated note, there are some differences between the tag systems on the two sites. For example, the tag (abstract-algebra) [is deprecated on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/abstract-algebra/info) and it is recommended to use [at least one top-level tag](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1457/why-are-mo-tags-formatted-as-they-are).

Comment: Thank you @MartinSleziak I will consider this for next posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Proposition 3.1 in https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10469-007-0009-z, for example.

*Buturlakin, A. A.; Grechkoseeva, M. A.*, [**The cyclic structure of maximal tori of the finite classical groups.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10469-007-0009-z), Algebra Logika 46, No. 2, 129-156 (2007); translation in Algebra Logic 46, No. 2, 73-89 (2007). [ZBL1155.20047](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1155.20047), [MR2356522](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2356522).